# Difference between Ubuntu 10.10 and 14.04 if kernel is same

Tags: 14.04, 10.10

I am using linux kernel 3.13.0-34 on Ubuntu 10.10.
On my other machine I am using same kernal i.e 3.13.0-34 but on Ubuntu 14.04. 
I dont understand what will be difference now between Ubuntu 10.10 or Ubuntu 14.04? 
Can any one guide me with this ?

This question is regarding Ubuntu Desktop edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu isn't a rolling release distribution. A release (eg 12.04, 14.04) will use and maintain a particular version of its software for the life of that release, adding updates like security patches but rarely* changing the major version.

It's between Ubuntu's releases, you'll see the major upgrades of software. You can see this in the [versions of `gnome-terminal` throughout the ages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-terminal&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all):

```
lucid (10.04LTS)   2.29.6-0ubuntu5
lucid-updates      2.30.2-0ubuntu1
precise (12.04LTS) 3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
trusty (14.04LTS)  3.6.2-0ubuntu1
utopic             3.6.2-0ubuntu1
vivid              3.14.2-0ubuntu3
```

So yes, your kernel may be current but **everything** else is critically out of date by over three years. You only need to spend a few minutes on the [Ubuntu Security Notices website](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) to see what horrors you haven't been protected against.

Upgrade immediately. Actually, to upgrade to the next still-supported release would need upgrading through 11.04 and 11.10 first. Both are dead with their package archives archived away. And 10.10 is *so* far gone I'd recommend a fresh install 14.04.

It seems unlikely that it be impossible to run this tool of yours on a later version of Ubuntu.

<sub>* There are some packages (like Firefox) that just track upstream and some others that [have exceptions made for on a case-by-case basis](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates), though it is important to state that these are not typical.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not just a kernel.

You have same kernel for both systems but

you don't have same Window Manager

you don't have same appliction

you don't have same filesystem hierarchy

you don't have same Desktop manager

you don't have same versions of services

etc ....

Indeed I can't just write all of what you don't have here, but in few they are totally different unless a same kernel.

The correct question will be What is in common between My systems instead of differences

Comment: Thanks Maythux.. , i just need to use traffic generation tool on machine with 10.10 ubuntu .. do u think it will make difference. I am having difficulties to update it using updates.

Comment: 10.10 is out of date and you can't get updates anymore so it's better to upgrade to a newest  and it's better to use LTS versions such as 12.04 or 14.04

Comment: yeah i am trying to do that .. but i cant do bec its not upgrading and the machine i have doesn't boot my usb, and i was trying to update it on internet.. till now havent found a solution